Congratulations! Cryptography is graduating!
It's a big day. You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Cryptography has already met our threshold for graduation-worthy sites, and today joins in the new design-independent graduation process! Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.
You've already had an election to have celebrated this previously, but now you will receive the remaining benefits detailed in this process, which include:

You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
You will be able to select your own community ads

In the coming months, the site will receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, and although you're looking at wait of several months, we wanted to give you the things we could give you now. There are also bound to be bugs as the new process gets rolled out so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on Meta Stack Exchange using the [graduating-sites] tag.
This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

That's great news!!

Thanks for the heads-up, Grace! And note the Q/A here on meta discussing site design, in case our designers need inspiration

And if the designers want to use random-looking strings, this question is collecting some.

Hi Grace, is there a reason why our site is still listed as public beta in Area 51? Or is it just that this is an issue with the current partial graduation business?

It's the latter

So we have the first and the last benefits noted above. When do we get the middle one? Please don't say 6-8 weeks :)

@mikeazo It's already enabled. No paths have actually been proposed since the graduation announcement, though.

@GraceNote, great. Is that something a moderator has to do or can anyone propose a migration path? How is it done?

@mikeazo Just make a meta thread demonstrating the need, anyone can do it. We'll then review it and then enable the path if it seems appropriate.
